# File transfer download no react on production build

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, file-transfer

I use filetransfer.download very good in dev mode (`ionic cordova run android`). But when I want use it in production mode (`ionic cordova run android --prod`), I don't see anything. actually, both of entry and error not called.
My code :

```
this.fileTransfer.download(encodeURI(url), <file-path> ,  false , some header ).then((entry) => {

          this.messageCtrlService.showAlert(JSON.stringify(entry.toURL()), 'Success');

       }, (error) => {
         this.messageCtrlService.showAlert(JSON.stringify(error), 'Error');

       });
```

**EDITED :**
When I build app with this command :

```
ionic cordova --minifycss --aot --optimizejs --release
```

Everythin is ok. Is anyway for prevent some plugin (like file-transfer) from minify? How?

Comment: is this inside `this.platform.ready()` ?

Comment: @suraj Yes, I initialize app in the first. actually when I run (ionic cordova run --minifyjs) file transfer not working. I looking for anyway for prevent from minify some files! (I mean file transfer plugin)

Comment: maybe you can get logs by using `ionic cordova run android --prod --verbose`

Comment: I can't see any point in logs @suraj

Comment: There seem to be a bunch of problems with running with prod flag according to the forums.. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-ionic-cordova-run-android-device-prod/102569 .. If it is related to minification or build process.. you could see if there is anything in the logs.

Comment: @suraj In my case, `–minifyjs`  is causing. but I don't get any error . Is anyway for write exception in minify files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this might help anyone, but in my case, the minification was making the code running faster, so one of my providers was executing the `this.fileTransfer = this.transfer.create();` before the `devideready` event could be fired.

I fixed it with the following:

```
constructor(private transfer: FileTransfer,
              private platform: Platform,
              private other: Other) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.fileTransfer = this.transfer.create();
    });
  }
```

Comment: this worked for me, was debugging for hours figuring out why the download file was not working. +1 for figuring out minification issue